# MySQL Table doesn't exist error when using MSQL Docker container/MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, xampp, mysql-workbench

It's my first time using Docker and MySQL Workbench. I was using XAMPP before to run my mysql local server and manage the database using phpMyadmin. And all is fine, then I decided to try running mysql server using Docker and I cannot get it to work.

My error is

```
  code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
  errno: 1146,
  sqlMessage: 'Table \'ToastHRMDB-dev.Employee\' doesn\'t exist',
  sqlState: '42S02',
```

And my query below that is working fine when I use XAMMP, but doesn't work in mysql Docker or probably workbench is the issue?

```
SELECT 
            Employee.id as id,
            Employee.employee_number as employeeNumber,
            Employee.first_name as firstName,
            Employee.middle_name as middleName,
            Employee.last_name as lastName,
            Employee.suffix as suffix,
            Employee.nickname as nickname,
            Employee.tr_email as trEmail,
            Employee.image_url as imageUrl,
            Employee.loginservice_id as authId,
            Role.definition as role
        FROM Employee
        INNER JOIN RoleMap ON Employee.id = RoleMap.employee_id
        INNER JOIN Role ON RoleMap.role_id = Role.id
        WHERE Employee.tr_email = ?
        AND Employee.is_del = 0`;
```

Here's the thing though. If I change all those table names in my query the exact casing same in the database then I can get it to run without error(using Docker/Mysql Workbench). For example changing `Employee` on my query to lowercase `employee`.

I don't want the my original query to change though. I cannot tell if this is just about some setting in Docker? Or in Mysql Workbench? I tried setting up my schema with different collation, like utf8 and ascii but no luck. Maybe I need to choose other charset type?

By the way here is the command that I ran to initialize my docker container

```
docker run --name mysql_5 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.37
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable or tell MySQL to use [lower case table name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) and [Identifier Case Sensitivity doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

For Example

```
docker run --name mysql_5 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.37 --lower_case_table_names=1
```